# Is there a good Rails plugin to expose a query interface to Angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Angular.js allows me to query a server resource cleanly from the client and pass up parameters which I'd like restrict how I query the server resource.

However in order to actually process those parameters on the server I need to write a load of code to safely consume such a query and then translate it into a Rails query.

Is there any nice gem that easily allows you to expose a rich way to query the database via REST in a safe and controlled way?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so and I dont think it would be a great idea.

A quick way would be (Rails 4):

```
# very important!
white_list  = [:age, :country, :gender]

query = User.all
params.slice(*white_list).each do |key, value|
  query = query.where(key => value)
end
```

An ambiguity would be when you want to call an existing `scope` instead of a basic `where`, but there is no obvious way to abstract it, so you should write some code.